# laravel Eloquent query WhereHas wrong result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables and relations as bellow
user
the user table:

| id | name | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 |
| 2 | xyz | Null |
| 3 | abx | 0 |

the book table:

| id | user_id | name | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | book1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | book2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | book3 | 0 |

relation is as this
user->books (HasMany)

```
return $this->hasMany(Book::class,'user_id','id');
```

my query is as bellow

```
User::with('book')
->WhereHas('book', function($query) {
                    $query->where(['active'=> 1]);
                   })
->where(['id'=> 1,'active'=>1])
->get();
```

This query is getting zero records because active is 0 in books

1. But i want to see all user record and if there is matching record with active 1 in book.
2. second is query user for active 1 or Null and for that if use `->orwhereNull('active')`
   All records changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to apply filter on related records (with()) instead of applying filter on whole query. So this way you will always get a list of users along with the list of active books only

```
User::with(['book'=> function($query) {
        $query->where('active', 1);
}])
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('active', 1)
          ->orWhereNull('active');
})
->get();
```

I have used [logical grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping) here so in case if you have more filter clauses to add in your query.

Or you can define a new relation in your user model to pick only active related books as

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function book()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
    public function active_books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class, 'user_id', 'id')
            ->where('active', '=', 1);
    }
}


User::with('active_books')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('active', 1)
              ->orWhereNull('active');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `id` and `active` column on both table, so I think you need to change your query like this :

```
User::with('book')
->WhereHas('book', function($query) {
         $query->where(['books.active'=> 1]); // books table active column
})
->where(['id'=> 1,'active'=> 1]) // users table id, active column
->get();
```

Comment: Sidenote, you shouldn't have to do `users.id` and `users.active` in the `where()` clause, since `books` isn't being `join()`'ed. It doesn't hurt anything, just for clarity :)

Comment: @Tim thanks for the explanation,  I've edited my answer

Comment: but if there is no record in book table it will not show user record also

Comment: It wont show user, if there no record match on books table. this is whereHas

Comment: @Droid thanks is there any other option like WhereHas?

Comment: You can try with `orWhere`

Comment: @Droid thanks but orWhere will bring the records even its not match

Comment: @Mr.SH Why you need _any other option like WhereHas_ when it serves your results ?

Comment: @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks I can work with any option , I just need to get users and if there is matching books, with WhereHas if books are not active then user is also not showing....

Comment: @Mr.SH I think you should rephrase your expected output in question with an example.It's confusing .

Comment: Dear I was very clear in my question , thanks so much